# How to represent $\frac{x^6}{(1-4x)^2}$ as a power series?

Tags: integration, functions, power-series

For the function $f(x) = \frac{x^6}{(1-4x)^2}$ , how could you represent this as a power series?

My first step is to express the function as $x^6 \times \frac{1}{(1-(8x-16x^2))}$ , and since $1/(1-x)$ is $\sum x^n$ , I believe the function can be expressed as $x^6 \sum (8x-16x^2)^n$ , but I think this is where I am wrong.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: You can integrate the geometric series $1/(1 - 4x)$ to get $1/(1 - 4x)^2$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. With Cauchy producct it is easy to see that

$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k$, hence

$\frac{1}{(1-4x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)4^kx^k$  for $|x|<1/4$, thus

$\frac{x^6}{(1-4x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)4^kx^{6+k}$  for $|x|<1/4$.

Comment: How did you determine the sums of 1/(1-x)^2 and 1/(1-4x)^2 ?

Comment: @HenryWalsh You can determine the power series for $(1-x)^{-2}$ by (a) evaluating higher derivatives at zero to get the Taylor series (b) squaring the power series for $(1-x)^{-1}$ or (c) taking the derivative of the power series for $(1-x)^{-1}$. After that, replace $x$ with $4x$.

Comment: You get $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k$  for $|x|<1$, via Cauchy product: $(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k)(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k)$. Then write $4x$ instead of $x$.